# Using new position when switching to fixed position

Tags: jquery, css, position

I am trying to make an element on my page scroll down with the page when you have scrolled down to a certain point. I have it switch to `position: fixed` when another element that moves hits it. The problem is that when it switches to `position: fixed` it moves about a quarter of the way down the page, because that's its original position on the page. Is there any way to use the position that its at when it switches to fixed instead of having it jump down to its original position?

Here's some code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
     var    top =  jQuery("accordion").offset().top - parseFloat(jQuery("#accordion").css("marginTop").replace(/auto/, 0));
     // what the y position of the scroll is
     var y = jQuery( "#navigation" ).offset().top + jQuery( "#navigation" ).height();

     // whether that's below the form
     if (y >= top) {
         // if so, ad the fixed class
         jQuery("#accordion").css('position','fixed');
     } else {
            // otherwise remove it
            jQuery("#options_accordion").css('position', '');
         }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the top position of your sticky element at the point you switch it to position: fixed. I've created a quick example to show you what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/BSpyM/

```
var $sticky = $('.sticky');
var $win = $(window);
var originalStickyPosition = $sticky.offset().top;

// Change this if you want it to switch at some point other
// than the top of the window
var switchPoint = 0;

$win.on('scroll', function (event) {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

    if ((originalStickyPosition - scrollTop) <= switchPoint) {
        if (!$sticky.hasClass('stuck')) {
            $sticky.css('top', switchPoint);
            $sticky.css('left', $sticky.offset().left);
            $sticky.addClass('stuck');
        }
    } else {
        if ($sticky.hasClass('stuck')) {
            $sticky.removeClass('stuck');
        }
    }
});
```